# VScode Dev Container : Override local settings

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

## TL;DR

VScode in Dev Container does not override local Workspace Settings with the Remote Settings

#### Exhaustive description of issue

I am developping with vscode devcontainers, and I absolutely love it :)
However, I have an issue with the automatic linting, on save.

I have the black linter in local, that works correctly, with the following configuration in the workspace settings (`.vscode/settings.json`):

```py
{
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.formatting.blackPath": "~/venv/.style-check/bin/black",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

In local, each time that I save my file, it runs the black formatter so that my code gets the correct layout and formatting. However in the devcontainer, it does not work properly.

I am running a custom image, based on the microsoft's python [official image](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/main/containers/python-3) that already includes all the usual linting libraries (black, flake8, bandit...).
It also already provides the custom remote `settings.json`, with the path where the binaries are installed :

```py
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/usr/local/bin/python",
    "python.formatting.blackPath": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/black",
    "python.linting.flake8Path": "/usr/local/py-utils/bin/flake8",
    ...
}
```

Black is correctly installed, I can manually run the formatter with `black my_file.py`, and everything works as expected.
VScode also correctly launches the formatter on save : after a ctrl+S on `myfile.py`, I could have a look at the logs by going to the `output` view of the integrated terminal, and choosing `Python` in drop-down menu.
These logs clearly show that vscode executed the `black` linter as expected, but using the local path (`"~/venv/.style-check/bin/black"`) which obviously did not work.
However, the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers#_container-specific-settings) insists on the fact that the remote settings should override the local workspace settings.

I also checked if the remote settings were correctly identified, by adding in my in `.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`, the example from the documentation linked just above. It immediately reflected in the remote container settings.json (`/home/vscode/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json`).

To summarize, it seems the container itself is perfectly set-up, but the vscode window isn't.
What is going on here ? Why are the remote settings not taken into account ?
I am running out of ideas at this point :/

(PS : I asked ChatGPT, which confusely said something about sync settings, but I didn't really get it. I just thought I would let you know this piece of information.)

Comment: You can try to use a new workspace for remote connection. As the official document said, the purpose of coverage is to maintain the consistency of user experience. It is best to avoid writing path-related settings in the workspace you are currently using. As far as I know, `blackpath` can be unspecified.

Comment: What is a new workspace ? I'm not sure to understand.  
Currently I have my project `research-ai` in which I open VScode. Then I use the command palette with `Dev Containers: Rebuild and Reopen in Containers`.
Do you have a link to the documentation ?    
I read most of it, if not all of it but did not find this :(
How does VScode do to locate black then ?

Comment: The document I refer to is the one you pasted in the article. The path in the vscode local setting overwrites the path in the container, resulting in an error. So I think you can delete the local path setting about black when using the container. In the process of actual use, I did not specify blackPath. I think it's possible to solve the problem by deleting the blackPath,

Comment: Yes ! What you precised in your first reply helped me :
`It is best to avoid writing path-related settings in the workspace you are currently using`
It does not really solve why vs code doesn't handle the correct path setting but at least it made it work.
Plus I am now more compliant to the usual guideline so that's perfect :)
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use **a new workspace** for remote connection.

As the official document said, the purpose of coverage is to maintain the **consistency** of user experience. It is best to **avoid** writing path-related settings in the workspace you are currently using.